# How to make conda-build work correctly and find the setup.py?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I am trying to create an anaconda python package. My `meta.yaml` looks like this:

```
package:
  name: liveprint-lib
  version: "0.1.0"

build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:
    - pip
    - python=3.7
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python=3.7
    - numpy
    - opencv

about:
  home: https://github.com/monomonedula/liveprint
  license: Apache License 2.0
  license_file: LICENSE.txt
  summary: Python utility library for dynamic animations projections
```

`build.sh`:

```
$PYTHON setup.py install
```

The folder structure:

```
.
├── bld.bat
├── build.sh
├── LICENSE.txt
├── liveprint
├── meta.yaml
├── README.md
├── resources
├── setup.py
└── test
```

The error I get when running `conda build .` is the following:

```
/home/vhhl/programs/anaconda3/conda-bld/liveprint-lib_1581422598848/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_/bin/python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `meta.yaml` file is missing a `source` section.  Also, it's usually best to keep your recipe files in a directory of their own, rather than in the top repo.  I recommend the following:

```
mkdir conda-recipe
mv meta.yaml build.sh bld.bat conda-recipe
```

Then, edit `meta.yaml` to add a `source` section, which points to the top-level directory of your repo.

```yaml
package:
  name: liveprint-lib
  version: "0.1.0"

source:
  # Relative path to the parent directory.
  path: ..

build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:
    - pip
    - python=3.7
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python=3.7
    - numpy
    - opencv
```

Then try:

```
conda build conda-recipe
```